# Checking if an object is a given generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, type-inference, typechecking, generic-type-argument

I have a viewControllers array in navigationController, and I need to find the certain vc and call popToViewController method. But type checking always failed.

How can I check if a vc is of a given type in Swift?

```
func popToViewController<T>(vcClass: T.Type, animated: Bool) {
        guard let mainVc = self.rootController else {
            return
        }

        let controllers = mainVc.viewControllers
        for vc in controllers {
            if vc is T  {   // always is false 
                _ = mainVc.popToViewController(vc , animated: true)
            }
        }
}
```

```
self?.router.popToViewController(vcClass: ViewController1.Type.self, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if type(of: vc) == T.self {
    _ = mainVc.popToViewController(vc , animated: true)
}
```

Or, if you want to check for a `vc` that can be cast into `T`:

```
if let _ = vc as? T {
    _ = mainVc.popToViewController(vc , animated: true)
}
```